# Trimming degree symbol on C#

Tags: c#, special-characters, texttrimming

Can anyone tell me why this is not working:

```cs
string txt = "+0°1,0'";
string degree = txt.TrimEnd('°');
```

I am trying to separate the degrees on this string, but after this, what remains on degree is the same content of txt.

I am using C# in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[string.TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=netcore-3.1) remove char at the end. In your example, '°' isn't at the end.

For example :

```
string txt = "+0°°°°";
string degree = txt.TrimEnd('°');
// degree => "+0"
```

If you want remove '°' and all next characters, you can :

```cs
string txt = "+0°1,0'";
string degree = txt.Remove(txt.IndexOf('°'));
// degree => "+0"
```

Comment: The value for degree in the second case should be "+0" and not "+0°1"

Comment: Note: will throw an exception if txt does not contain the degree symbol.

Comment: @SaiGummaluri has added a safe solution.

Comment: Biju Kalanjoor's solution is safest.
SaiGummaluri's answer give a invalid result.

Answer (score 1):

```
string txt = "+0°1,0'";
if(txt.IndexOf('°') > 0) // Checking if character '°' exist in the string
{
   string withoutdegree = txt.Remove(txt.IndexOf('°'),1);
}
```

Comment: What does this add that the other answers missed?
This will also throw an exception if `'°'` does not appear anywhere.

Comment: `if(txt.IndexOf('°') > 0)` is true when ° is in txt beacause `IndexOf` return -1 if the searched char is absent. This solution is the safest.

Answer (score 1):

Another safe way of handling the same is using the [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) method. You will not have to bother to verify the presence of the character in this case.

```
string txt = "+0°1,0'";
var str = txt.Split('°')[0]; // "+0"
```

```
string txt = "+01,0'";
var str = txt.Split('°')[0]; // "+01,0'"
```

You can use this to remove *all* the '°' symbols present in your string using [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1)

```
string txt = "+0°1,0'°°";
var text = txt.Replace(@"°", ""); // +01,0'
```

Edit: Added a safe way to handle the OP's exact query.